# Python: vectorizing a structured linear system solve

Tags: linear-algebra, python, numpy

**Overview**

I am looking for a way to solve a structured linear system in Python without using a for loop (preferably using vectorization, if possible).

**Background**

Consider the following linear system:
\begin{align}
    \begin{pmatrix} 
         E_0 \\
         F_1 & E_1 \\
         & F_2 & E_2 \\
         && \ddots & \ddots \\
         &&& F_{K-1} & E_{K-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
    \begin{pmatrix} 
         x_0 \\ x_1 \\ x_2 \\ \vdots \\ x_{K-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
    =
    \begin{pmatrix} 
         b_0 \\ b_1 \\ b_2 \\ \vdots \\ b_{K-1}
    \end{pmatrix}
\end{align}
where $E_i, F_i \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, and 
$x_i, b_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$ for $i = 0, \ldots, K-1$

Further, the $E_i$ are invertible for $i = 0, \ldots, K-1$.

Then this system can be solved through forward substitution:

Solve $E_0 x_0 = b_0$

for $i = 1, \ldots, K-1$:
Solve $E_i x_i = b_i - F_i x_{i-1}$

**My Current Implementation**

The block matrices $E_i$ and $F_i$ are available by calling `Ek(i)` and `Fk(i)`.

Currently $x$ and $b$ are shaped as a numpy arrays with shape $K \times n$ so that `x[k]` gives $x_k$, and so forth.

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.sparse.linalg import spsolve

# define K and n, create b and initialize x

x[0] = spsolve(Ek(0), b[0])
for i in range(1, K):
    x[i] = spsolve(Ek(i), b[i] - Fk(i) @ x[i-1])
```

Can this be vectorized? I would like to not use a for loop here since they are quite slow in Python.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your explanation, you solve the large problem using forward substitution. This implies that you are solving your large problem successively: you first need $x_{i-1}$ before you can solve for $x_{i}$. This means that you need to loop, there is no way to avoid this.

However, for each subproblem, you use the `spsolve` routine, dedicated to solving sparse systems. Why? Are the submatrices $E_{i}$ really sparse? What is the order of magnitude of `n`? What sparse storage format do you use for the $E$ and $F$ matrices?

Another approach would be to consider your full matrix as a banded matrix and use `scipy.linalg.solve_banded`. If you have numpy linked to an optimized BLAS/LAPACK like MKL, this might also prove to be quite fast.

Could you elaborate a bit more on your problem (sizes, structure of the $E$ and $F$ matrices)? And if you feel up to it, make the comparison between the forward substitution approach (using a for loop) and the banded matrix approach and post it here...

Answer (score 0):

I think the way to go is to use some library code at that point. Vectorization is quite a low-level  (hardware near) optimization which seems a bit unnatural to tackle via python. Search for Lapack or BLAS vectorized operations. including them into your code might end up in a couple of extra lines, but will potentially spare you the misery of doing it by hand.[scipy.linalg.lapack)](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/linalg.lapack.html)

Also, before you think about vectorization, consider whether there are operations which you can run thread-parallel. Depending on your machine, that might already give you significant performance increase.

I'm no expert on performance in python, is there a chance of calling your substitution recursively might give a performance boost?